# Selenium Java - Downloading images from Pinterest

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

So I'm trying to create a web crawler for a school project that goes to different pages of Pinterest and downloads all the images it finds (can be all html elements if necessary, just need the pictures primarily). I have most of the code working, but I'm running into a problem in getting the pictures themselves. I know its possible to use a robot and have it right click the page and save the page, but I'm looking for a way to get all the pictures into one folder, and make it repeatable over many pages. The code I have now goes to the page, and scrolls down a few times to get around 150 pictures on the page, now what I need to do is grab all pictures on the page. Every time I try to find the picture by an xpath, they all seem to be different.

```
driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/tptpins/end-of-school-year/");
Thread.sleep(2000);

JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {

    jsx.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}
```

Comment: You can try make screenshot and cut the image from it, i use selenium with c# and its work fine for me. (have special method in .Net)

Comment: I would do that, but my program requires me to go to hundreds of pages, each with almost 100 pictures per page.